# Algorithm to split an array into P subarrays of balanced sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, parallel-processing, load-balancing

I have an big array of length N, let's say something like:

```
2 4 6 7 6 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 3 1
```

I need to split this array into P subarrays (in this example, `P=4` would be reasonable), such that the sum of the elements in each subarray is as close as possible to sigma, being:

```
sigma=(sum of all elements in original array)/P
```

In this example, `sigma=15`.

For the sake of clarity, one possible result would be:

```
2 4 6    7 6 3 3   3 4 3 4    4 4 3 3 1
(sums: 12,19,14,15)
```

I have written a very naive algorithm based in how I would do the divisions by hand, but I don't know how to impose the condition that a division whose sums are (14,14,14,14,19) is worse than one that is (15,14,16,14,16).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is that one result worse than the other? If you can clarify that in your head, you can write it in code. Is it simply that you want to minimise sum of the differences (from the ideal result, 15)? There are many approaches to this. For example the sum of differences (as mentioned above), the sum of the squares of the differences (which more heavily penalises answers further from the ideal), or even something like standard deviation.

Comment: You might want to have sum-of-squared-error as a badness measure: you square the difference of every sum with sigma, and sum them up. `(14,14,14,14,19)` would have a badness of 20, while `(15,14,16,14,16)` would have a badness of 4. Of course, you can play with the exponent.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry for not being more clear and thank you for your prompt answer. I think minimising either the sum of differences or squares of the differences would work. Is there any known way to do it "on the fly"? The actual array I have contains about half a million numbers so I don't think considering all possible combinations first and then selecting the most balanced one is an option.

Comment: Pass, I'm afraid. That's a whole different question! (And, as such, might be better asked as a separate question.) I'm not aware of any easy way to do this without some kind of "brute force" - which you probably want parallelised.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously similar to the 0-1 knapsack problem, I'd start looking around there. But that one has no efficient solution known, so I'm afraid this one hasn't either. Perhaps move to cs.stackexchange.com?

Comment: What do you mean by subarray. A consecutive subarray or it is more like a subsequence?

Answer (score 6):

First, let’s formalize your optimization problem by specifying the input, output, and the measure for each possible solution (I hope this is in your interest):

> Given an array *A* of positive integers and a positive integer *P*, separate the array *A* into *P* non-overlapping subarrays such that the difference between the sum of each subarray and the perfect sum of the subarrays (sum(*A*)/*P*) is minimal.
>
> **Input**: Array *A* of positive integers; *P* is a positive integer.
> **Output**: Array *SA* of *P* non-negative integers representing the length of each subarray of *A* where the sum of these subarray lengths is equal to the length of *A*.
> **Measure**: abs(sum(*sa*)-sum(*A*)/*P*) is minimal for each *sa* ∈ {*sa* | *sa* = (*A*<sub>*i*</sub>, …, *A*<sub>*i*+‍*SA*<sub>*j*</sub></sub>) for *i* = (Σ *SA*<sub>*j*</sub>), *j* from 0 to *P*-1}.

The *input* and *output* define the set of valid solutions. The *measure* defines a measure to compare multiple valid solutions. And since we’re looking for a solution with the least difference to the perfect solution (minimization problem), *measure* should also be minimal.

With this information, it is quite easy to implement the `measure` function (here in Python):

```py
def measure(a, sa):
    sigma = sum(a)/len(sa)
    diff = 0
    i = 0
    for j in xrange(0, len(sa)):
        diff += abs(sum(a[i:i+sa[j]])-sigma)
        i += sa[j]
    return diff

print measure([2,4,6,7,6,3,3,3,4,3,4,4,4,3,3,1], [3,4,4,5]) # prints 8
```

Now finding an optimal solution is a little harder.

We can use the [Backtracking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) for finding valid solutions and use the *measure* function to rate them. We basically try all possible combinations of *P* non-negative integer numbers that sum up to length(*A*) to represent all possible valid solutions. Although this ensures not to miss a valid solution, it is basically a brute-force approach with the benefit that we can omit some branches that cannot be any better than our yet best solution. E.g. in the example above, we wouldn’t need to test solutions with [9,…] (*measure* > 38) if we already have a solution with *measure* ≤ 38.

Following the pseudocode pattern from Wikipedia, our `bt` function looks as follows:

```py
def bt(c):
    global P, optimum, optimum_diff
    if reject(P,c):
        return
    if accept(P,c):
        print "%r with %d" % (c, measure(P,c))
        if measure(P,c) < optimum_diff:
            optimum = c
            optimum_diff = measure(P,c)
        return
    s = first(P,c)
    while s is not None:
        bt(list(s))
        s = next(P,s)
```

The global variables `P`, `optimum`, and `optimum_diff` represent the problem instance holding the values for *A*, *P*, and *sigma*, as well as the optimal solution and its measure:

```py
class MinimalSumOfSubArraySumsProblem:
    def __init__(self, a, p):
        self.a = a
        self.p = p
        self.sigma = sum(a)/p
```

Next we specify the `reject` and `accept` functions that are quite straight forward:

```py
def reject(P,c):
    return optimum_diff < measure(P,c)
def accept(P,c):
    return None not in c
```

This simply rejects any candidate whose measure is already more than our yet optimal solution. And we’re accepting any valid solution.

The `measure` function is also slightly changed due to the fact that `c` can now contain `None` values:

```py
def measure(P, c):
    diff = 0
    i = 0
    for j in xrange(0, P.p):
        if c[j] is None:
            break;
        diff += abs(sum(P.a[i:i+c[j]])-P.sigma)
        i += c[j]
    return diff
```

The remaining two function `first` and `next` are a little more complicated:

```py
def first(P,c):
    t = 0
    is_complete = True
    for i in xrange(0, len(c)):
        if c[i] is None:
            if i+1 < len(c):
                c[i] = 0
            else:
                c[i] = len(P.a) - t
            is_complete = False
            break;
        else:
            t += c[i]
    if is_complete:
        return None
    return c

def next(P,s):
    t = 0
    for i in xrange(0, len(s)):
        t += s[i]
        if i+1 >= len(s) or s[i+1] is None:
            if t+1 > len(P.a):
                return None
            else:
                s[i] += 1
            return s
```

Basically, `first` either replaces the next `None` value in the list with either `0` if it’s not the last value in the list or with the remainder to represent a valid solution (little optimization here) if it’s the last value in the list, or it return `None` if there is no `None` value in the list. `next` simply increments the rightmost integer by one or returns `None` if an increment would breach the total limit.

Now all you need is to create a problem instance, initialize the global variables and call `bt` with the root:

```py
P = MinimalSumOfSubArraySumsProblem([2,4,6,7,6,3,3,3,4,3,4,4,4,3,3,1], 4)
optimum = None
optimum_diff = float("inf")
bt([None]*P.p)
```

Answer (score 4):

@Gumbo 's answer is clear and actionable, but consumes lots of time when length(A) bigger than 400 and P bigger than 8. This is because that algorithm is kind of brute-forcing with benefits as he said.

In fact, a very fast solution is using **dynamic programming**.

Given an array A of positive integers and a positive integer P, separate the array A into P non-overlapping subarrays such that the difference between the sum of each subarray and the perfect sum of the subarrays (sum(A)/P) is minimal.

> **Measure:** [image], where [image] is sum of elements of subarray [image], [image] is the average of P subarray' sums.
>
> This can make sure the balance of sum, because it use the definition of [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

Persuming that array A has N elements; **Q(i,j)** means the minimum Measure value when split the last i elements of A into j subarrays. **D(i,j)** means `(sum(B)-sum(A)/P)^2` when array B consists of the i~jth elements of A ( `0<=i<=j<N` ).

The minimum measure of the question is to calculate Q(N,P). And we find that:

```
Q(N,P)=MIN{Q(N-1,P-1)+D(0,0); Q(N-2,P-1)+D(0,1); ...; Q(N-1,P-1)+D(0,N-P)}
```

So it like can be solved by **dynamic programming**.

```
 Q(i,1) = D(N-i,N-1)

 Q(i,j) = MIN{ Q(i-1,j-1)+D(N-i,N-i); 
               Q(i-2,j-1)+D(N-i,N-i+1); 
               ...; 
               Q(j-1,j-1)+D(N-i,N-j)}
```

So the algorithm step is:

```
 1. Cal j=1:

    Q(1,1), Q(2,1)... Q(3,1)

 2. Cal j=2:

    Q(2,2) = MIN{Q(1,1)+D(N-2,N-2)};

    Q(3,2) = MIN{Q(2,1)+D(N-3,N-3); Q(1,1)+D(N-3,N-2)}

    Q(4,2) = MIN{Q(3,1)+D(N-4,N-4); Q(2,1)+D(N-4,N-3); Q(1,1)+D(N-4,N-2)}

 ... Cal j=...

 P. Cal j=P:

    Q(P,P), Q(P+1,P)...Q(N,P)

The final minimum Measure value is stored as Q(N,P)! 
To trace each subarray's length, you can store the 
MIN choice when calculate Q(i,j)=MIN{Q+D...}
```

> [image] space for D(i,j);
>
> [image] time for calculate Q(N,P)
>
> compared to the **pure brute-forcing algorithm** consumes [image] time.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken here, one more approach is dynamic programming.

You can define *P*[ *pos*, *n* ] as the smallest possible "penalty" accumulated up to position *pos* if *n* subarrays were created. Obviously there is some position pos' such that

P[pos', n-1] + penalty(pos', pos) = P[pos, n]

You can just minimize over pos' = 1..pos.

The naive implementation will run in O(N^2 * M), where N - size of the original array and M - number of divisions.

Comment: btw, if the numbers are all non-negative, then using Monge property of the matrix, you can do this in O(NM) time and use Hirschberg's trick to use O(N) space. Also there is a reduction from this problem to a DAG and then solves the problem even faster when k is large, see this paper: http://65.54.113.26/Publication/652857/finding-a-minimum-weight-k-link-path-in-graphs-with-monge-property-and-applications

Answer (score 1):

Working code below (I used php language). This code decides part quantity itself;

```php
$main = array(2,4,6,1,6,3,2,3,4,3,4,1,4,7,3,1,2,1,3,4,1,7,2,4,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,4,5,7,8,9,8,0);
$pa=0;
for($i=0;$i < count($main); $i++){
$p[]= $main[$i];
if(abs(15 - array_sum($p)) < abs(15 - (array_sum($p)+$main[$i+1])))
{
$pa=$pa+1;
$pi[] = $i+1;
$pc =  count($pi);

$ba = $pi[$pc-2] ;

$part[$pa] = array_slice( $main,  $ba, count($p));
unset($p);
}
}
print_r($part);
for($s=1;$s<count($part);$s++){
echo '<br>';
echo array_sum($part[$s]);
}
```

code will output part sums like as below

```
13
14
16
14
15
15
17
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering whether the following would work:

Go from the left, as soon as `sum > sigma`, branch into two, one including the value that pushes it over, and one that doesn't. Recursively process data to the right with `rightSum = totalSum-leftSum` and `rightP = P-1`.

So, at the start, sum = 60

```
2 4 6 7 6 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 3 1
```

Then for `2 4 6 7`, sum = 19 > sigma, so split into:

```
2 4 6     7 6 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 3 1

2 4 6 7     6 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 3 1
```

Then we process `7 6 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 3 1` and `6 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 3 1` with `P = 4-1` and `sum = 60-12` and `sum = 60-19` respectively.

This results in, I think, O(P*n).

It might be a problem when 1 or 2 values is by far the largest, but, for any value >= sigma, we can probably just put that in it's own partition (preprocessing the array to find these might be the best idea (and reduce sum appropriately)).

If it works, it should hopefully minimise sum-of-squared-error (or close to that), which seems like the desired measure.

Answer (score 0):

I propose an algorithm based on backtracking. The main function chosen randomly select an element from the original array and adds it to an array partitioned. For each addition will check to obtain a better solution than the original. This will be achieved by using a function that calculates the deviation, distinguishing each adding a new element to the page. Anyway, I thought it would be good to add an original variables in loops that you can not reach desired solution will force the program ends. By desired solution I means to add all elements with respect of condition imposed by condition from if.

```
sum=CalculateSum(vector)
Read P
sigma=sum/P
initialize P vectors, with names vector_partition[i], i=1..P
list_vector initialize a list what pointed this P vectors
initialize a diferences_vector with dimension of P
//that can easy visualize like a vector of vectors
//construct a non-recursive backtracking algorithm
function Deviation(vector) //function for calculate deviation of elements from a vector
{
  dev=0
  for i=0 to Size(vector)-1 do
  dev+=|vector[i+1]-vector[i]|
  return dev 
}
iteration=0
//fix some maximum number of iteration for while loop
Read max_iteration
//as the number of iterations will be higher the more it will get  
//a more accurate solution
while(!IsEmpty(vector))
{   
   for i=1 to Size(list_vector) do
   {
       if(IsEmpty(vector)) break from while loop
       initial_deviation=Deviation(list_vector[i])
       el=SelectElement(vector) //you can implement that function using a randomized   
                               //choice of element
       difference_vector[i]=|sigma-CalculateSum(list_vector[i])|
       PutOnBackVector(vector_list[i], el)
       if(initial_deviation>Deviation(difference_vector))
          ExtractFromBackVectorAndPutOnSecondVector(list_vector, vector)
    }
    iteration++
    //prevent to enter in some infinite loop
   if (iteration>max_iteration) break from while loop
```

}
You can change this by adding in first if some code witch increment with a amount the calculated deviation.
      aditional_amount=0
      iteration=0
      while
      {
         ...
         if(initial_deviation>Deviation(difference_vector)+additional_amount)
             ExtractFromBackVectorAndPutOnSecondVector(list_vector, vector)
         if(iteration>max_iteration)
         {
            iteration=0
            aditional_amout+=1/some_constant
         }
       iteration++
       //delete second if from first version 
      }

Comment: It's always a good idea to give a high-level explanation of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very similar to, or the same as, the [minimum makespan scheduling problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling), depending on how you define your objective. In the case that you want to minimize the maximum `|sum_i - sigma|`, it is exactly that problem.

As referenced in the Wikipedia article, this problem is NP-complete for `p > 2`. Graham's [list scheduling algorithm](http://www.risc.jku.at/education/courses/ws96/intropar/sched/index_5.html) is optimal for `p <= 3`, and provides an approximation ratio of `2 - 1/p`. You can check out the Wikipedia article for other algorithms and their approximation.

All the algorithms given on this page are either solving for a different objective, incorrect/suboptimal, or can be used to solve any problem in NP :)

Comment: Although the OP doesn't state it clearly, the desired result is a set of divisions of the original array. The elements cannot be reordered. This constraint makes the problem far more tractable.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the case of the one-dimensional **bin packing problem**, see http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/bin-packing.shtml. In the associated book, [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000693), Skienna suggests a **first-fit decreasing approach**. I.e. figure out your bin size (mean = sum / N), and then allocate the largest remaining object into the first bin that has room for it. You either get to a point where you have to start over-filling a bin, or if you're lucky you get a perfect fit. As Skiena states "First-fit decreasing has an intuitive appeal to it, for we pack the bulky objects first and hope that little objects can fill up the cracks."

As a previous poster said, the problem looks like it's NP-complete, so you're not going to solve it perfectly in reasonable time, and you need to look for heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed this and did as follows;

1. create an initial sub-arrays array of length given sub arrays count. sub arrays should have a sum property too. ie `[[sum:0],[sum:0]...[sum:0]]`
2. sort the main array descending.
3. search for the sub-array with the smallest sum and insert one item from main array and increment the sub arrays sum property by the inserted item's value.
4. repeat item 3 up until the end of main array is reached.
5. return the `initial` array.

This is the code in JS.

```js
function groupTasks(tasks,groupCount){
  var  sum = tasks.reduce((p,c) => p+c),
   initial = [...Array(groupCount)].map(sa => (sa = [], sa.sum = 0, sa));
  return tasks.sort((a,b) => b-a)
              .reduce((groups,task) => { var group = groups.reduce((p,c) => p.sum < c.sum ? p : c);
                                         group.push(task);
                                         group.sum += task;
                                         return groups;
                                       },initial);
}

var tasks = [...Array(50)].map(_ => ~~(Math.random()*10)+1), // create an array of 100 random elements among 1 to 10
   result = groupTasks(tasks,7);                             // distribute them into 10 sub arrays with closest sums

console.log("input array:", JSON.stringify(tasks));
console.log(result.map(r=> [JSON.stringify(r),"sum: " + r.sum]));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Max Flow algorithm.

Comment: A link or an explanation of this algorithm would be courteous.

Comment: I highly doubt this, as it seems the problem is NP-complete.