# Algorithm to distribute text evenly across N columns

Tags: algorithm, text, layout, multiple-columns, partitioning

What is the algorithm that implements CSS's multi-column layout with balanced fill?

Mathematical formulation: given a list of positive numbers (those would be the heights of the items to arrange), distribute them in order into N lists such that the difference between the list with the largest sum and the list with the smallest sum is the minimum of all possible arrangements.

Comment: By "distribute them in order" you mean that the order remains fixed?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn yes, you can't scramble the text :)

Comment: What can be the possible limit on the length of the list and N?

Comment: So, convert the list to a cumulative one, then divide the last element by N to obtain IdealColumnSize. return the closest element to elementIndex * IdealColumnSize for elementIndex ranging from 1 to N-1. I.e. for N = 2 this is one element, the closest to the half-value.

Comment: @nellex why does it matter? Both can be infinite.

Comment: Please provide an example. Or a link to one.

Comment: @JimMischel look at the big table of libraries on http://luapower.com  -- items have variable height due to headers and occasional wrapping yet they are almost perfectly distributed across 7 columns.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn I'm not sure but I think it's a global optimization problem because the element that you choose as your cutting point affects the height of all subsequent columns and thus the `max_sum - min_sum` quantity.

Comment: This looks to me like a variation of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120729/algorithm-to-split-an-array-into-p-subarrays-of-balanced-sum

Comment: @JimMischel thanks, looks like exactly the same problem, differently formulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the list to a cumulative one, then divide the last element by N to obtain IdealColumnSize:

For example:

```
2, 3, 6, 8, 3, 4, 2
```

Yields the cumulative list:

```
2, 5, 11, 19, 22, 26, 28
```

Say we want to divide it into 3. IdealColumnSize is 9 1/3.
Now for indexes 1 to N-1, select the closest element in the cumulative list.

The closest to 9 1/3 is 11, so the first three numbers go in column 1.

The closest to 18 2/3 is 19, so one number goes into column 2.

The remaining items go in the last column.

Comment: Very clever, it's like computing the absolute height of each item and the absolute height of each column in an imaginary 1-column layout and comparing them so that the errors don't accumulate 

Comment: I don't understand why people say that the problem is NP-complete in the other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120729/algorithm-to-split-an-array-into-p-subarrays-of-balanced-sum). Thoughs?

Comment: @capr If you can rearrange the items to be able to find a better arrangement, then you can get better answers.  But there are a lot of rearrangements, and no good way to find the absolute best.  If you can't rearrange elements, then you only need to think about where to break the existing list.

Comment: Consider this: 15,1,10,1,1,1,1. The number of columns is 3. The "divide and take the nearest" would give {15}, {1}, and {10,1,1,1,1}, which obviously does not not give "difference between the list with the largest sum and the list with the smallest sum is the minimum of all possible arrangements" (15-1=14). The {15}, {1,10}, and {1,1,1,1} gives better result (15-4=11).